# how to send data from component to worker on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, web-worker

could you please tell me how  send data from component to worker on button click?

I tried like that not working

```
// xx.postMessage([first.value,second.value]);
```

could you please suggest where i am doing wrong .I want to do some background calculation and return result to component.

here is my code

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import worker from "./workerfile";
import WebWorker from "./setup";
export default function App() {
  const buttonHan = () => {
    alert("==g=");
    // xx.postMessage([first.value,second.value]);
    //console.log("Message posted to worker");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let xx = new WebWorker(worker);
    //xx.addEventListener("message", event => {
    // });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox1</h1>
      <button onClick={buttonHan}>BTN</button>

      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

code

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-forest-s3guc?file=/src/App.js:212-263

Comment: Could it be 'cuz you're declaring xx inside useEffect? I think you should declare it as regular code at the beginning of your App component, to use it afterwards

Comment: if there's no cost to instantiating the object, you can just do it in buttonHan too,,,make it local to the button click method...depends what the constructor does

Answer (score -1):

This is the way i'd do it, idk if it's the supreme right way but i haven't had any problem declaring vars like this.
Also it's extremely useful when it comes to work with third party event handlers

```
export default function App() {
    let xx = new WebWorker(worker);  // Declare worker
    // Constants declarations

    const buttonHan = () => {
       alert("==g=");
       xx.postMessage("[first.value,second.value]");
       console.log("Message posted to worker");
    };

    useEffect(() => {
       xx.addEventListener("message", event => {
           console.log(event)
       });
    }, [xx]);  // useEffect executes when worker is setted
    // this should be done even if variable is not a state

    ...
```

Comment: When do you call xx.terminate() in this example?